# XLOOKUP and return number between brackets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two sheets. sheet A containing sales quantity, and sheet B containing customer satisfaction score. Both contains names and IDs, but in sheet B, names and IDs are concatenated (separeted by dash) and it also removes zeroes from left of IDs (It already comes from db in this format).

Example:
cell A1 in sheet A : 00990252310
cell A1 in sheet B : 990252310 - John Doe

I need to match people's ID and return the sales number from sheet A, and the score (that is between brackets) from sheet B. (Sales, I'll do later. I need to figure out first the score)

Example of score value (I need extract the "7"):
cell D1 in sheet B : 10 [7]

I put together this formula below, but it's not working. I can only think that the error maybe in using LEN to an array, but since it's inside XLOOKUP, I thought it should work fine.

`=XLOOKUP(B2,TEXT(LEFT(sheet B!A:A,SUM(LEN(sheet B!A:A)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(sheet B!A:A,{"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"},"")))),"00000000000"),MID(sheet B!B:B,FIND("[",sheet B!B:B)+1,FIND("]",sheet B!B:B)-FIND("[",sheet B!B:B)-1))`

I can't solve this. Help me please, guys. =(

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Please add screenshots of your data as it's a little hard to visualize from your description.

Comment: I'm sorry. I added the screenshots and edited the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a variant of this:

```
=INT(XLOOKUP(INT(B2),INT(LEFT(I2,FIND(" -",I2,1)-1)),SUBSTITUTE(MID(J2,FIND("[",J2,1)+1,LEN(J2)),"]","")))
```

[image]

The useful thing here is that `INT` converts a text representation of a number to a number. Given that a number written with leading zeroes is stored as text, if you wrap it in INT, it removes the leading zeroes and becomes useful for the lookup.

We're then using `XLOOKUP` to:

1. Remove the leading zeroes from the ID on the main page
2. Lookup that value in the column of values represented by everything to the left of  `-` (space, dash) in the SALESPERSON column.
3. Return the text found after the `[` in the SCORE column
4. Remove the `]`
5. Convert the result into a number with `INT`

Comment: I think what makes the asker's approach extra confusing is doing the string manipulation inside the lookup function. I was going in the same direction, using INT, but I believe it would be cleaner to complete the XLOOKUP tightly, then wrap the return in the string manipulation (instead of the other way around). It would certainly be easier to figure out what was done when looking at it weeks or months later.

Comment: Fair enough. At first I had the `SUBSTITUTE` on the outside, but figured it didn't matter much either way. I do wonder about memory usage sometimes and, as a SQL programmer, while I can't say I 100% understand how it works in Excel, my instinct is to reduce early. I did have another thought that using `LET` might be useful here, but didn't want to get into it tbh.

Comment: Thank you very much, guys. :)

Comment: I just did a minor modification to your formula, @FlexYourData . Sometimes there are no names in the column I, so there's no " -" to `FIND`.

`=INT(XLOOKUP(INT(B2),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-",I2))INT(LEFT(I2,FIND(" -",I2,1)-1)),INT(I2)),SUBSTITUTE(MID(J2,FIND("[",J2,1)+1,LEN(J2)),"]","")))`

I don't know if it's the most elegant solution, but it worked. :)

Comment: Looking a little deeper into XLOOKUP, it supports wildcards. There might be even better way to do this...

Comment: You are of course right and I feel a bit dumb for not remembering that! Going to edit.

Comment: That's weird. Using your new formula in my original spreadsheet, if I change ´I2´ to ´sheet B!A:A´ and ´J2´ to ´sheet B!B:B´, it doesn't return "7". It returns "1", but there's no "1" in the immediate near brackets.

If you want to test that, just add more salespeople in sheet B. Btw, that first formula I posted above just worked fine. I'm just trying to learn more now. :)

Comment: Heh. You're right. Rushed through it and didn't test properly. I'm going to remove the extra stuff as I don't have time to fix it right now.

Comment: That's ok. Thank you again for your time.